# Sufficient statistic for a function of the parameter

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

We know that if $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ then $f(T)$ is a sufficient statistic for $f(\theta)$ if $f(.)$ is a one -one function.
But,what if $f$ is not one one?
For example, in case of Bernoulli $(p)$ ,how to find the sufficient statistic for $p(1-p)$?

Comment: Can you prove that the sample variance is a sufficient statistic for $p(1-p)$?

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong.  I believe the sample mean is in fact a sufficient statistic for population variance in this case.

Comment: What do you call "a sufficient statistic for $\theta$"?

Comment: If $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$ then it is sufficient for any function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, then

- $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $f(\theta)$ for any function $f$,
- $f(T)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ for any injective function $f$.

Since you want a sufficient statistic for $f(\theta)$, this function doesn’t need to be injective.